# Wrap first div of a div

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to wrap or replace the first div and p which is in a div called entry-content :

```
var outer = document.getElementById(".entry-content div");
outer.innerHTML = "<div id='wrap'>"+outer.innerHTML+"</div>"
```

and

```
var outer = document.getElementById(".entry-content p");
outer.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '"+outer.innerHTML+"'</script>"
```

Output (wrap):

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div><div id="wrap">lala</div></div>
<p><script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://"</script></p>
</div>
```

or the best output would be (wrap and replace):

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div id="wrap">lala</div>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://"</script>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `.entry-content div` is not a valid ID. Why do you think you could use `getElementById` with something that looks like a selector? Anyways, it looks like you want to **remove** the first `div` and `p` element but keep their contents, is that correct? Wrapping is something different.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. Since you did not provide a "before" version of your HTML, I'm not sure what you actually want to do. If this does not help, please let me know and update your question with a better description of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to remove the element but keep its content. "Unwrap" if you want to call it that.

This can be done with a little DOM manipulation:

```
function unwrap(element) {
    // insert all the element's children *after* the element itself
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var children = element.childNodes;
    var before = element.nextSibling;

    // reverse iteration always inserting the previous sibling before
    // the next one
    for (var i = children.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        before = parent.insertBefore(children[i], before);
    }

    // remove the element
    parent.removeChild(element);
}
```

Then all you have to do is pass a reference to the element you want to remove to the function.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpNFm/)

If you really want to replace the element though, then you just have to move all child nodes to the new element and replace the old element with the new one. I call the function "rewrap" here (because "replace" doesn't indicate that the content is copied):

```
function rewrap(element, new_element) {
    // append all the element's children to the new element
    while (element.firstChild) {
        new_element.appendChild(element.firstChild);
    }

    // replace old element with new
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, element);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpNFm/1/)