# Remove child element but keep its content

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to remove the `strong` element during the onclick event?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span onclick="testfx();"><strong>Test without styles</strong></span>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testfx() { alert('test'); }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to remove the tags only( and preserve the text), you could make a selection of the `span` and then use `execCommand('removeFormat')`.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of your problem. If you want to remove the `strong` element while preserving the content, have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906257/wrap-first-div-of-a-div/16906446#16906446).

Comment: I think you should alter the title for more generic context so it can be more easy for people find this.. something like "Remove child element but keep it's content".. something like that. Just a tip.

Comment: I would like to preserve the content

Comment: In that case, have a look at the `unwrap` function I linked to in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be handling (javascript) events in a script file and not in the HTML. It will help you with,

- Separation of functionality (the "behavior layer") from a Web page's
  structure/content and presentation
- Best practices to avoid the problems of traditional JavaScript
  programming (such as browser inconsistencies and lack of scalability)
- Progressive enhancement to support user agents that may not support
  advanced JavaScript functionality

You could try this,

```
var x = document.getElementById("test");
var y = document.getElementById("testChild");
x.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.removeChild(y);
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HkrC5/2/)

**EDIT**

If you just want to remove the "strong" effect do this,

```
var x = document.getElementById("test");
var y = document.getElementById("testChild").innerHTML;
x.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.innerHTML = y;
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HkrC5/3/)

Comment: +1 for the 3 helpful tips (which everybody should be following anyway)

Comment: *"You should be handling (javascript) events in a script file"*. You mean in a script file *or* a script element, right ?

Comment: @dystroy I meant, in a separate file :) and reference the file.

Comment: By the way, I don't think this answer is helpful. It doesn't even look for the `strong` element.

Comment: @badZoke *"I meant, in a separate file :"* .Then please accept this -1. Using script elements is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @dystroy acceptable, sure, but I believe it's generally preferable to use external sheets if at all possible and as such makes perfect sense to not recommend the script element in this case. It seems intuitive to keep the languages separate for ease of development at the very least, not to mention cashing benefits for scripts used on multiple pages among other things.

Comment: @DACrosby Open any important web site source (for example SO) : you'll see script elements. Sometimes it's better to keep things simple and avoid loading additional files.

Comment: @dystroy that's the most stupidest -1 ever. I never said it's taboo to use script elements, I've given reasons as to why it should be in a separate file. "*Sometimes it's better to keep things simple and avoid loading additional files.*" Why not write all the js inline then?

Answer (score 15):

Well, here it is: http://tinker.io/1f282/1

```
el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var toRemove = this.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0];

    if (!toRemove) {
        return;
    }

    while (toRemove.firstChild) {
        el.appendChild(toRemove.firstChild);
    }
});
```

(where `el` is your span). Note one very important thing: You should not mix javascript in your html. It's bad in all kinds of ways, you can just google "separation of concerns" and "unobtrusive javascript" to see why.

Comment: What if `toRemove` has more than one child or zero?  Maybe `while (toRemove.firstChild) { el.appendChild(toRemove.firstChild); }`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I agree that this isn't a general solution to this problem. I'll add that in since that is a useful case, thanks.